# Adding Project Tasks using AtTask API

Tags: php, attask, workfront-api

I am attempting to add a new task to a project in WorkFront (formerly known as AtTask). I have successfully been able to create a CURL connection to post the request, but the API only takes the task name and durations values. Any dateTime fields are ignored. Any suggestions on what I can do to set the task due date or the required completion dates? It must be really simple, but I am some how missing the it.

```
    $taskName = urlencode($_GET['newtask']);
    $attask_newtask_url = 'https://[my server name]/attask/api/v4.0/task';
    $now = time()+2880;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $attask_newtask_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
        'name'=>$taskName,
        'projectID'=>[my project id],
        'sessionID'=>$sessionID,
        'duration'=> (720/1440),
        'projectedStartDate'=>"07/27/2011"
    )));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projected duration is a system calculated field that is not editable. To alter your start dates you would need to edit the plannedStartDate.

for example your code should be.

```
 $taskName = urlencode($_GET['newtask']);
    $attask_newtask_url = 'https://[my server name]/attask/api/v4.0/task';
    $now = time()+2880;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $attask_newtask_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
        'name'=>$taskName,
        'projectID'=>[my project id],
        'sessionID'=>$sessionID,
        'duration'=> (720/1440),
        'plannedStartDate'=>"07/27/2011"
    )));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot that plannedStartDate is the manually managed value. I made the change, but it seems that even when I use plannedStartDate, the task in still created with the project start date. So I am wondering if it is related to either the format of my date variable or if it related to a task constraint ("start as soon as possible"). Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I figured it out. It was due to the task constraint date. I make the following change to my test code and it seemed to work:
'plannedStartDate'=>"02/10/2015",
'plannedCompletionDate'=>"2/15/2015" ,
'taskConstraint'=>"FIXT"

Thanks for the help.